# Do we have Silverlight control for Baidu Map

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, baidu, baidu-map

My current project is bit old one. It has developed in Visual Studio 2008 using silverlight. Currently we have Bing Map in our project. Where it uses bing map control.

My problem is now we need to implement this in china and we need to use BAIDU map. I checked online for any solutions. I know that Microsoft has stopped supporting Silverlight long time back.

Is silverlight has support for BAIDU map or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps Silverlight control never supported China, nor used Baidu.